# Visual Studio 2022 Keeps Trying to Remote Debug When Remote Is Off

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022

I have a project that at one point I did some remote debugging.  It found the issue and fixed it.  I then turned off remote debugging, but when I try to run the project it is still trying to remote debug.  I have deleted the hidden .vs folder thinking that may do it.  Is this in a settings file or something?  Thank you for any help.

[image: Remote Debug Off]

[image: Error]

Please ignore the 426 warnings :)  I am fixing those.

Comment: Hi, why is the Debug tab of the project properties empty when you are performing remote debugging? Under normal circumstances, you should check "Use remote machine", and follow it with the corresponding IP address and Authentication mode of your target computer. Also please check "Enable native code debugging". For details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT That is my point.  I am not trying to remote debug.  I am trying to debug locally yet it errors in trying to connect to a remote machine.  I had used it before, but cleared this info out, yet it continues to try to remote debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for anyone out there that may have this issue.  I turned remote debugging back on, connected to the remote machine to debug.  I then cleared the machine name out and turned off remote debugging and now it works locally.